# angularjs showing a tab if condition is met in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to split this ng-repeat loop in angularjs? I have a set of tabs and the data is found in workspace in workspaces. I want to basically check a condition `ng-if "savedSettings=='account'"`, show specific tab. `ng-if"savedSettings=='shelf'"` show tab. How can I work this conditional render in?

There are four tabs found in this workspace.

```html
<li ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" class="workspace.activeclass">
    <a id="workspace.tabid" href="{{workspace.hrefid}}" data-toggle="tab"> {{workspace.name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-show` directive:

```
<li ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
    class="workspace.activeclass"
    ng-show="workspace.tabid == savedSetting">

    <a id="workspace.tabid" href="{{workspace.hrefid}}" data-toggle="tab"> {{workspace.name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-show Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)